# apk file required for creating mobile app for magento

Tags: mobile, application

[image]we are trying to devolop a mobile app for magento site.

I want to know about is there any apk file or Activation key  required for creating mobile app.

is it a open source or is it paid one?

please guide me about this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not find an APK file in Magento. An APK is your app, ready to be installed on a Android phone (such as EXE on Windows). The APK file will be the product of your mobile app development.

Depending on *how* you are going to connect to your Magento shop, you will need to set up SOAP or REST credentials in Magento.

Comment: will magento community edition supports "Activation key" for mobile apps? = we are trying to generate a android app through magento site.

it's asking for "Activation Key ".

I want to know what is the "Activation key"? how it's going to be usefull.... 

if i click on that " Activation Key", it's redirecting to "enterprise edition"

Comment: I don't know what kind of Activation Key you mean. Where in the backend do you need to enter it?

Comment: please see updated question......

Comment: Is that XmlConnect (Main Menu Point "Mobile") that you're using? I cannot find that screen.

Comment: yes, in admin panel > mange mobile section.....

Comment: According to the xml (https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror/blob/1746ec3708fbe307aa8e599fdcc0211e2ce71126/app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/etc/config.xml#L304) the link should be http://magentocommerce.com/product/mobile. But that one is also redirecting. So it's not primarily a problem of the Shop, but more one from the Magento website.